# RxAndroid & Otto Wait for multiple async events to send data to server

Tags: android, facebook, rx-java, rx-android, otto

I have an Android app in which I need to register to GCM , ask the user for facebook authorization and get the token, have the user fill a form and so on...

Once that's all done I want to send all of that info to my server.

I was wondering if there is a simple way to implement this kind of behavior with RxAndroid & Otto ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each task you define (register to gcm, auth user on fb, get token, etc) should be `Observable` returning something (for example boolean to say whether request was sucessfull or not). Then you can use [zip operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)
so when all the requets are finished your function defined in zip is called and there you can check if all previous requests was succesfull and if yes just send all that info to your server.